# Microsoft ODBC for Oracle on Windows 2008 R2 x64

Tags: oracle, odbc, windows-server-2008

I have server under Windows Server 2003 with Oracle 10 32bit. There are several ODBC data sources configured in ODBC Data Source Administrator.

Now I need to move all that system to Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.
I've installed OS, Oracle server 12c x64, Oracle client 12 x64.
Now I need to configure my ODBC data sources, but there is no Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver.

Where can I find this driver to configure ODBC data source?

(I've tried 32bit tool from SystemWOW64, it has this driver but shows me exception "The Oracle(tm) client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle version 7.3 (or greater) clien costware installation." As far as I could say it looks for 32bit client, but there is no such)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" does not exist for 64 bit. Microsoft provides only a 32-bit version.

You have to download and install the driver from Oracle: [ODBC
Developer Center](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-098976.html) or 
[64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

The 32-bit ODBC driver (no matter if from Microsoft or from Oracle) does not work together with an 64-bit Oracle Client, the architectures have to match.